# SQL select data from database on based on two criteria

Tags: php, sql

I have made a PHP event calander where users can add events based on two options: Show each year, show once. When the users chooses show each year i only save the day and month in my database,
for showing once i also save the year.

But how can i retrieve this data and show the event once or each year.

My code:

```
$sqlEvent = "SELECT titel,content,id,added FROM calendar WHERE `maand` =     '$month' AND `dag` = '$day'";
$resultEvents = mysql_query($sqlEvent);


while ($events = mysql_fetch_array($resultEvents)){
echo "<strong>Event nummer:</strong> ".$events['id']."<br>";
echo "Added: ".$events['added']."<br>";
echo "Title: ".$events['title']."<br>";
echo "Details: ".$events['details']."<br>";
```

This shows the events every year, but how can i show the event with 'year' != 0 only once?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT titel,content,id,added FROM calendar WHERE 
`maand` =     '$month' AND `dag` = '$day' limit 1";
```

This will limit your result just to 1 record. I am not sure if this is what you want. If you are not wanting to limit your results to just 1 record, can you expand on what you want.

Comment: I mean if the year is 0 (show every year) i want to show it every year, when year is =! 0 example: 2013 i want to show it only on 2013.